# Отмена действий макроса до момента перед началом его работы

Tags: vba, ms-word

Здравствуйте.
Есть макрос на VBA для преобразования документа MSWord.
Необходимо реализовать отмену всех действий макроса.

На текущий момент реализовано так:

```
Dim undoCount
...
undoCount = 0
...
If checkbox1.value = True Then
    Selection.typeText "text1"
    undoCount = undoCount + 1
Else
    Selection.typeText "text2"
    Selection.typeText "text3"
    undoCount = undoCount + 2
End If
...
For i=1 to undoCount
    ActiveDocument.Undo
Next
```

Не нравится, что ветвления и циклы надо учитывать.
Есть подозрение, что это - быдлокодие.

Comment: Наверное, вам нужно это: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms477952(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Сводится к `Application.OpenUndoTransaction <Имя>` + `Application.CloseUndoTransaction`.

Comment: Ну и в той же статье есть кастомные undo/redo, это покрывает все случаи по идее.

Comment: @VladD круто, то что нужно. Сделайте, пожалуйста, ответом.

Comment: Подождите, кажется, это только для MS Project :-\ Сейчас попробую в Word'е.

Comment: Ага, в Word'е зато есть StartCustomRecord. Сейчас напишу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно уметь группировать несколько действий в одну группу для Undo/Redo. Для этого можно использовать undo record.

Вот [эта статья](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh420330.aspx) описывает использование для MS Word. Пример оттуда:

```vb
Dim objUndo As UndoRecord 

' работа этой функции будет оформлена как один элемент списка Undo/Redo     
Sub AddDocMetadata() 
Dim rngFooter As Range 

Set objUndo = Application.UndoRecord 

' Начинаем кастомную запись действий для undo, устанавливаем своё название
objUndo.StartCustomRecord ("Add Doc Metadata") 

  ' сами действия:   
  Set rngFooter = ActiveDocument.Sections(1) _ 
        .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range 

  With rngFooter 
        .Delete 
        .Fields.Add Range:=rngFooter, Type:=wdFieldFileName, Text:="\p" 
        .InsertAfter Text:=vbTab & vbTab 
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart 
        .Fields.Add Range:=rngFooter, Type:=wdFieldAuthor 
  End With 

' заканчиваем запись
objUndo.EndCustomRecord 

End Sub
```

Заметьте, что здесь, в отличие от [аналогичной фичи MS Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms477952%28v=office.12%29.aspx), вызов `Undo` во время записи custom record'а [отменяет *все* действия от начала](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh420330.aspx#Anchor_2). Это может быть не то, что вам надо.

Comment: Жаль, что эта фишка отсутствует в Word 2003 :( Приходится использовать свой вариант со счетчиком? :(

Comment: @ReinRaus: А вот эта фишка не поможет: http://stackoverflow.com/a/661312/276994? Я не могу попробовать, у меня нет 2003-го word'а.

Comment: Забавный способ. Попробую его.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь :)

Comment: @ReinRaus: Сработало? Круто! (Всегда пожалуйста!)

Answer (score 2):

Для старых версий Word можно применить следующий костыль:
Создаем закладку с уникальным именем и если требуется, то делаем Undo, пока закладка не исчезнет, если нужно оставить изменения, то удаляем закладку.

```
Const undoBookmark = "undoBookmark__"

Sub startUndoRecord()
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add undoBookmark
End Sub

Sub undoAllActions()
    While ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists( undoBookmark )
        ActiveDocument.Undo
    Wend
End Sub

Sub confirmAllActions()
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks( undoBookmark ).Delete
End Sub
```

Идея костыля взята здесь:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/661312/276994
но там много лишнего, реальные задачи гораздо проще, чем множество вспомогательных действий, которые реализованы там